# I am unable to start Influxdb server

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

I am unable to start InfluxDB server. InfluxDB server abruptly closes or fluctuates without fully starting.

While trying to start with Windows PowerShell it is showing the below error:

> 2023-06-25T13:51:17.278591Z     info    InfluxDB starting       {"log_id": "0idi0X6l000", "version": "1.8.10", "branch": "1.8", "commit": "688e697c51fd"}
> 2023-06-25T13:51:17.278591Z     info    Go runtime      {"log_id": "0idi0X6l000", "version": "go1.13.8", "maxprocs": 8}
> run: open server: listen: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8088: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
> PS D:\InfluxData\influxdb-1.8.10-1>

Comment: It looks like something else has the port it needs open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that port 8088 is busy and InfluxDB cannot use it hence it fails.

It might be the case InfluxDB is running already so check if this is the case.

If it's not you can:

1. Check which process is holding port 8088 using [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) command
2. Configure InfluxDB to use the [different port](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/administration/ports/)

More information: [JMeter + Grafana: How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana)